# Replicating the strcmp() function from string.h library

Tags: c, c-strings, strcmp, function-definition

I am trying to replicate the strcmp() function from the string.h library and here is my code

```
/**
 * string_compare - this function compares two strings pointed
 * by s1 and s2. Is a replica of the strcmp from the string.h library
 * @s1: The first string to be compared
 * @s2: The second string to be compared
 *
 * Return: On success, it returns:
 * 0 if s1 is equal to s2
 * negative value if s1 is less that s2
 * positive value if s1 is greater than s2
 */

int string_compare(char *s1, char *s2)
{
        int sum = 0, i;

        for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0'; i++)
                sum += (s1[i] - s2[i]);
        for ( ; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
                sum += (s1[i] - 0);
        for ( ; s2[i] != '\0'; i++)
                sum += (0 - s2[i]);

  

        return (sum);
}
```

I tried my function using this sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s1[] = "Hello";
    char s2[] = "World!";

    printf("%d\n", string_compare(s1, s2));
    printf("%d\n", string_compare(s2, s1));
    printf("%d\n", string_compare(s1, s1));
    return (0);
}
```

And I get the following output,

```
-53
-500
0
```

But I should be getting:

```
-15
15
0
```

Why am I getting such a result??

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Your approach does not make much sense. Why do you compare all characters and don't stop at first difference? With your function you would get 0 for `"ab"` and `"ba"` or for `"bbb"` and `"abc"`

Comment: I expect this to crash on any strings that are different lengths, because the conjunction of the test, `s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0'`, allows buffer overrun. Also, you seem to be making a checksum, which fails to differentiate "ab" from "ba".

Comment: Regardless which approach you take, you need to check `s1` and `s2` for `NULL` before you start iterating over each. E.g. `if (!s1 && !s2) return 0; if (s1 && !s2) return 1; if (!s1 && s2) return -1;`

Comment: `string_compare()` will give bizarre results if one of the parameters happens to be a null pointer... Look into `assert()`, as a minimum, to trap these errors during development.

Answer (score 3):

This approach is incorrect.

Let's assume that the first string is `"B"` and the second string is `"AB"`.

It is evident that the first string is greater than the second string in the lexicographical order.

But the result will be negative due to this for loop

```
    for ( ; s2[i] != '\0'; i++)
            sum += (0 - s2[i]);
```

though the function shall return a positive value.

Moreover there can occur an overflow for the variable `sum` of the type `int`.

Also the function should be declared at least like

```
int string_compare( const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

because passed strings are not changed within the function.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int string_compare( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    while ( *s1 && *s1 == *s2 )
    {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
    }

    return ( unsigned char )*s1 - ( unsigned char )*s2;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am trying to understand your code,and what do you mean when you put `while ( *s1 && *s1 == *s2)`. I am new to pointers, and programming in general so, can you please explain it for me?? @Vlad from Moscow

Comment: @LeuelAsfaw `while (*s1)` means *"while we're not at the end of string 1"*, and `while (*s1 == *s2)` means *"while the current character of string 1 is equal to the current character of string 2"*. Put it all together, and you have *"while (we're not at the end of string1 AND the current characters are equal) { increment the pointers to point to the next character }"*

Comment: @chqrlie You are right. I was not attentive.:)

Answer (score 3):

You are overcomplicating very simple function.

```
#define UC unsigned char

int mystrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int result;
    while(!(result = (UC)*s1 - (UC)*s2++) && *s1++);
    return result;    
}
```

Comment: This shaves a few instructions off at the end by writing the result directly in the inner loop. Important if you call this a lot.

Comment: @chqrlie assuming chars > 127 as valid

Comment: @0___________ -- you are correct. My bad. I thought you were using `unsigned`, not `unsigned char` -- sorry. That's a common optimization (unrolling 4-bytes at a time).

Comment: @chqrlie leftover

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are arrays of characters terminated with a null character (`\0`).

When you pass a string to a function, you are passing a pointer to its first element. That pointer is passed *by value*. You can modify that pointer within the function without any side-effects on the string it points to, as long as you don't dereference and assign to the address it points to.

That's why the pointer math from
[0___________'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73337984/15261315) works.

> ```
> int mystrcmp1(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
>     int result = 0;
>     while(!(result = *s1 - *s2++) && *s1++);
>     return result;     
> }
> ```

`*s1++` could be rewritten as `*(s1++)` to disambiguate. `s1++` returns the current pointer to the beginning of the first string, *and* then increments the pointer so it points to the next character. That pointer is then dereferenced to give us the character. The same happens with the `s2` pointer.

Then we're comparing them by subtraction. If they're the same, we get `0`, which in C is false in a boolean context. This result is assigned to `result`.

We can now see that the loop continues while corresponding characters in the two strings are equal *and* while dereferencing `s1` does not give us the null terminator.

When the loop continues it means there was either a difference or we reached the end of the first string.

The difference will be stored in `result`, which the function returns.

Comment: Edited as I had a hard to spot UB in code.